# calculation of binary power like $a^b$ where a,b are binary numbers

Tags: binary

Is it possible to calculate power of binary number like $a ^ b$where a,b both are binary numbers.

Comment: Yes.  It is possible.

Answer (score 2):

One of the faster and simpler methods is [exponentiation by squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). It is based on taking advantage of the fact that an integer power can be easily reduced by dividing the power by two (possibly with remainder):

$$
a^b = a^{\left \lfloor \frac{b}{2} \right \rfloor  2 + b \% 2}
$$

where $\left \lfloor \frac{b}{2} \right \rfloor$ denotes the integer quotient of $b$ and $2$, and $b \% 2$ denotes the remainder (i.e. $1$ for an odd number, $0$ for and even number). We can then rewrite this as:

$$
a^b = (a^2)^{\left \lfloor \frac{b}{2} \right \rfloor} a^{b \% 2}
$$

Which now reduces the problem into squaring $a$ (which is trivial), and repeating the same algorithm with power $\left \lfloor \frac{b}{2} \right \rfloor$ and base $a^2$. This will recursively reduce the exponent at each step, ensuring termination.

Comment: In exponentiation by squaring method only the component $b$ is in binary. however i want the method in which $a$ as well as $b$ both the term is in binary form.

Comment: @Aria Only $b$ needs to be an integer, but $a$ can certainly be an integer (in binary form or not). You then just use binary multiplication to calculate $a^2 = a * a$ (and to multiply by $a$ if $b$ is odd). The fact that these numbers are in binary doesn't really matter in this case. The binary aspect is only relevant here in that it makes calculating $b/2$ and $b \% 2$ far more efficient than an arbitrary division, because they can be done with a right shift of one bit (i.e. `>> 1` in most programming languages) and by taking only the lowest bit (i.e. `& 1`) respectively.

Comment: What this algorithm does is give an efficient way of computing an integer power of anything (even matrices or other groups/associative operations), using only multiplication.

Comment: can you please give example with binary numbers like 0010^ 0111.

Comment: I'm not sure why you see the need to do it by hand with binary numbers; binary is mostly useful when doing things by computer, but here it goes:

Comment: $0010^{0111} = (0010*0010)^{0011} * 0010 = 0100^{0011} * 0010 = (0100*0100)^{0001} * 0100 * 0010 = 10000 * 0100 * 0010 = 1000000 = 128_{10}$. If you found that hard to follow, that is because binary is not a good way to do calculations by hand; its much easier to just compute $2^7$.

Comment: in my coding everything is in terms of binary, so for raising power i have to convert it in decimal. that's why i need it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23797/discussion-between-john-colanduoni-and-aria).